# AlertView delegate method alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton not called Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uialertview

I'm creating this alert view and trying to use the delegate method alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton but it isn't being called.
Documentation says it is going to be deprecated in iOS9 but I'm using iOS8

```
    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Edit collection name", message: "", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK")

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput

    alert.show()
```

*update as Duncan pointed out UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS8.

Comment: Aswell as setting the delegate to self, you need to declare that your class adheres to the *UIAlertViewDelegate* protocol.

Comment: UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS 8. You're supposed to use UIAlertController instead.

Comment: I already adhered to UIAlertViewDelegate. Woah I missed that UIAlertView was deprecated. Thanks Duncan

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS8. Credit to @Duncan C